# Uniform Convergence and Injectivity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function and let $\phi: [0,1] \to [a,b]$ where $\phi(x) = (b-a)x + a$. Clearly $\phi$ is injective and $f \circ \phi$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

A Theorem in my book says that there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ such that $p_n \to f \circ \phi$ uniformly.

Then my book defines $q_n = p_n \circ \phi^{-1}$ and claims that $q_n \to f$ on $[a,b]$ uniformly.

I have the following 2 questions:

1. I don't understand why injectivity is important in this case. I know injective $\iff$ left inverse, but here $\phi^{-1}$ is a right inverse which I know exists since $\phi$ is surjective.
2. Also why is it true that $q_n \to f$ uniformly? It seems like the author just applied $\phi^{-1}$ to both sides, but why is uniform convergence maintained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of the proof is as follow:

Given a function $g$ defined on the interval $[0,1]$ we construct explicitely a sequence of polynomials $(q_n)$ (as for example the Bernstein polynomials) defined on the same interval and convergent uniformly to the function $g$.

Now clearly $\phi$ is  **bijective** so given a function $f$ defined on the interval $[a,b]$ then the function $g=f\circ \phi$ is defined on $[0,1]$ so from the foregoing there's a sequence of polynomials $(q_n)$ convergent uniformly to $g$ so

$$\sup_{y\in[0,1]}|q_n(y)-g(y)|=\sup_{y=\phi^{-1}(x)\in[0,1]}|q_n(\phi^{-1}(x))-g(\phi^{-1}(x))|\to0$$

and clearly $p_n=q_n\circ \phi^{-1}$ is a polynomial defined on $[a,b]$ and $f=g\circ \phi^{-1}$ so
$$\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|p_n(x)-f(x)|\to0$$
so the sequence of polynomials $(p_n)$ is uniformly convergent to $f$.